# How do I merge these two functions that are performing the same thing to different variables?

Tags: javascript, function

I need help in merging these two function that are performing the same action of adding all the elements in a list

```
function totalSpendings() {
  let totalSpending = 0;
  if (this.spendingList.length > 0) {
    totalSpending = this.spendingList.reduce(function (
      totalValue,
      curentValue
    ) {
      totalValue += curentValue.inputSpending;
      return totalValue;
    },
    0);
  }
  this.spending_summary.textContent = totalSpending;
  return totalSpending;
}

function totalEarnings() {
  let totalEarning = 0;
  if (this.earningList.length > 0) {
    totalEarning = this.earningList.reduce(function (totalValue, curentValue) {
      totalValue += curentValue.inputEarning;
      return totalValue;
    }, 0);
  }
  this.earning_summary.textContent = totalEarning;
  return totalEarning;
}
```

I tried out this way to create a common function but was unsuccessful :

```
    total(arg1,arg2,arg3){

let total = 0;
    if (arg1.length > 0) {
        total = arg1.reduce(function (totalValue, curentValue) {
            totalValue += arg3;
            return totalValue;
        }, 0);

    }
    arg2.textContent = total
    return total;
```

}

Comment: you can pass the variable in the method function as function arguement

Comment: The keyword you are looking for is "parameter", and it will be covered in the first few lessons of any programming course.

Comment: What I attempted to do was create a total() method which took in three arguments that correspond to the common variables between the two function so it was total(arg1,arg2,arg3). This would translate to for spending: total(this.SpendingList, this.spending_summary, currentValue.inputSpending). Please advise on the error that I may have made. I think the error is with parameter 'currentValue.inputSpending' but am unsure how I can rewrite that part

Answer (score 0):

You could try to implement a callback function, e.g.

```js
const spending_summary = {};
const earning_summary = {};
const spendingList = [
  {inputSpending: 1},
  {inputSpending: 2},
];
const earningList = [
  { inputEarning: 1},
  { inputEarning: 2},
];

function total(list, reducer) {
  if (list && list.length > 0) {
    return list.reduce(reducer, 0);
  }
  return 0;
}

spending_summary.textContent = total(spendingList, (total, current) => total += current.inputSpending);
earning_summary.textContent = total(earningList, (total, current) => total += current.inputEarning);

console.log(spending_summary);
console.log(earning_summary);
```

Comment: Please note that I removed all the `this` references for the sake of simplicity...